# JSON Schema - Can not convert Array to Boolean

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm testing NewtonSoft's JsonSchema package and have the following code

```
string schemaJson = File.ReadAllText("c:\\temp\\schema.txt");
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
```

When I test the schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ it executes correctly, but when I run the above code locally I get an `ArgumentException` "Can not convert Array to Boolean".

Here is the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The Root Schema",
  "description": "The root schema is the schema that comprises the entire JSON document.",
  "default": {},
  "required": [
    "checked",
    "dimensions",
    "id",
    "name",
    "price",
    "tags"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "checked": {
      "$id": "#/properties/checked",
      "type": "boolean",
      "title": "The Checked Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": false,
      "examples": [
        false
      ]
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "$id": "#/properties/dimensions",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Dimensions Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": {},
      "examples": [
        {
          "height": 10.0,
          "width": 5.0
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "width",
        "height"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "width": {
          "$id": "#/properties/dimensions/properties/width",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The Width Schema",
          "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            5
          ]
        },
        "height": {
          "$id": "#/properties/dimensions/properties/height",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The Height Schema",
          "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            10
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "id": {
      "$id": "#/properties/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "The Id Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        1
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "$id": "#/properties/name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "The Name Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": "",
      "examples": [
        "A green door"
      ]
    },
    "price": {
      "$id": "#/properties/price",
      "type": "number",
      "title": "The Price Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": 0,
      "examples": [
        12.5
      ]
    },
    "tags": {
      "$id": "#/properties/tags",
      "minItems": 3,
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The Tags Schema",
      "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
      "default": [],
      "examples": [
        [
          "home",
          "green"
        ]
      ],
      "items": {
        "$id": "#/properties/tags/items",
        "type": "string",
        "title": "The Items Schema",
        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
        "default": "",
        "examples": [
          "home",
          "green"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the (invalid) JSON that I use on the website to test the schema validation:

```
{
    "checked": "false",
    "dimensions": {
        "width": 5,
        "height": 10
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.5,
    "tags": [
        "home",
        "green"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is that all the code required to cause the error? The JSON itself is valid, so without being able to replicate the error, it's unlikely anyone can help.

Comment: That is 100% an executable test case.

Comment: I don't work with .net, so let me ask someone else in our community to come take a look =]

Comment: Those are the problems I expect the validator to report. Loading the schema is what fails. To be clear, this is the Newtonsoft library

Comment: @dbc I was able to repro the problem [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zoTXQs).  It appears he is attempting to use the obsolete `JsonSchema` component from the Newtonsoft.Json package instead of using `JSchema` from Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers - that was the problem, I'm pleased the question held enough information for you to work that out! I usually have "Warnings as errors" to prevent compilation so didn't notice the obsolete warning. If you could add this as an answer I will gratefully accept it.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to reproduce your problem [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zoTXQs).

It appears that you are using the `JsonSchema` component from the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) package.  As noted in the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchema.htm), this component is obsolete and has been replaced by a newer `JSchema` component which is in a separate [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) package.

If you use the newer component your schema [loads as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoTb6P).